# Strange error in an algorithm written in Python to find the Least Common Multiple

Tags: python-3.x, stress-testing, greatest-common-divisor

For educational purposes, I am trying to build an efficient algorithm to find the Least Common Multiple. I already have a quadratic and slow implementation for that. I am trying to build a new one. My new implementation uses a math property involving the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD) and the Least Common Multiple (LCM).

Basically: For any two positive integers a and b,

```
LCM(a, b) * GCD(a, b) = a * b
```

I am using Python 3 for that.

I have a very efficient implementation for GCD (it uses another math property, but it is pointless to talk about that):

```
def euclidean_gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        a_prime = a%b
        return euclidean_gcd(b,a_prime)
```

My implementation for LCM is:

```
def lcm_fast(a,b):
    return (int((a*b)/(euclidean_gcd(a,b))))
```

However, when I call:

```
lcm_fast(1023473145,226553150)
```

I get as an output:

```
46374212988031352
```

The correct answer would be a close number:

```
46374212988031350
```

I am a beginner (second year on the Applied Math major), why is this happening?

I am not sure if I could grasp the concept of integer overflow, but, according to my understanding above a little research I did, there is no integer overflow in Python.

I did stress testing and tried to find this mistake in a easier to understand case. However, the problem seems to happen only with really big numbers. Bellow you can check my stress testing for that:

```
import random

#defina a fronteira máxima dos testes randômicos

print ("insira um número para ser o final do intervalo de testes aleatórios")
bound_right = int(input())

#versão lenta, ou naive

def check_elem_in_list(list_1,list_2):
    for element in list_1:
        if element in list_2:
            return element
    else:
        return False

#nested loops, vai ter comportamento quadrático

def lcm_slow(num_1,num_2):

    list_of_num_1_prod = []
    list_of_num_2_prod = []
    max_nums = max(num_1,num_2)
    end_range = max_nums +1
    for i in range(1, end_range):
        list_of_num_1_prod.append(i*num_1)
        list_of_num_2_prod.append(i*num_2)
        if check_elem_in_list(list_of_num_1_prod,list_of_num_2_prod) != False:
            return (check_elem_in_list(list_of_num_1_prod,list_of_num_2_prod))

def euclidean_gcd(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    else:
        a_prime = a%b
        return euclidean_gcd(b,a_prime)

def lcm_fast(a,b):
    return (int((a*b)/(euclidean_gcd(a,b))))


# está dando pau com os inputs 1023473145, 226553150
# vou fazer stress testing
#primeiro, fazer função para gerar testes

a_in = random.randint(1,bound_right)
b_in = random.randint(1,bound_right)


while (lcm_slow(a_in,b_in)==lcm_fast(a_in,b_in)):
    a_in = random.randint(1,bound_right)
    b_in = random.randint(1,bound_right)
    print (a_in,b_in,"OK",lcm_fast(a_in,b_in),lcm_slow(a_in,b_in))
    if (lcm_slow(a_in,b_in)!=lcm_fast(a_in,b_in)):
        print (a_in, b_in,"OPS",lcm_fast(a_in,b_in),lcm_slow(a_in,b_in))
        break
```

#

EDITED AFTER SOME COMMENTS/ANSWERS TO THE ORIGINAL PROBLEM

Inside this problem, a new problem arrives.
I am building this for a platform. My solution is right. After the comment from Blender. I did that (which was my original solution):

```
def lcm_fast(a,b):
    a = ((a*b)/(euclidean_gcd(a,b)))
    return a
```

The problem is that I receive this message failing on the platform's test cases:

```
Failed case #1/42: Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong. 

Input: 18 35 Your output: 630.0 Correct output: 630 (Time used: 0.01/5.00, memory used: 9613312/536870912.)
```

That's funny. If I avoid the approximation with `int()`, the code is right for big numbers. However, without the conversion from `float` to `int`, I am unable to provide the answer on the desired format.

Comment: Is this Python 3?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I already fixed the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're converting the result of your division back into an integer with `int()` because "regular" integer division results in a float. CPython's floats have a fixed precision, so your conversion back and forth will result in lost information for sufficiently large numbers.

Avoid losing precision and perform floor division with `//`, which returns an integer:

```
def lcm_fast(a,b):
    return (a * b) // euclidean_gcd(a,b)
```

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to upload in a platform. This platform runs multiple tests. My implementation keeps failing in one test: 

Failed case #1/42: Cannot check answer. 

Perhaps output format is wrong. Input: 18 35 Your output: 630.0 Correct output: 630 (Time used: 0.01/5.00, memory used: 9613312/536870912.)

Comment: @Harry: From what's written in your question, you should not have floats anywhere in your code. Your comment says that you do have them, however. It'd be helpful if you posted your full code.

Comment: @Harry: Also, the double divide symbol `//` isn't a typo. `3 // 2 == 1`, but `3 / 2 == 1.5`. They're different operators.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not express my self in a very nice way. Both codes cause erros.  Using the int() conversion, I lost precision. Without the int() I am not answering in the desired format... @Blender

Comment: Ohhh, I am sorry. I didn't catch that. I didn't know //  would be a special thing. I thought that after python 2 changed to python 3, // and / would be the same... @Blender

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, standard division (`/`) operations will automatically promote to float, while integer division (`//`) will always return an `int`.

Thus, python can handle arbitrarily large `int`s, at some point your data is being treated as a float rather than an int, subjecting it to floating point precision error.

(I see someone else also typed up a similar answer while I was writing this up and feel obligated to make note of this before being bashed to death for copying someone else's answer.)